# DATEDIFF function displayed error output in sqlserver

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i tried the code in mysql it is working well

```
 select car_id,cust_id,due,DATEDIFF(NOW(),due) as elap from rental where car_id = '1'
```

issue date 2019-10-16  return date 2019-10-17
have to calucalated elap result displayed in -1 it is working well.

if i tried in sqlserver it produced wrong output

```
select cat_id,cust_id,date,due,DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),due) as elap from rental where cat_id = '1'
```

have to calucalated elap result displayed in 1.wrong output  right on is -1 i don't know what is the error on sqlserver code

Comment: Try switching the order of your dates. Try: `DATEDIFF(dd, due, GETDATE())` if you believe the result should be -1.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server's [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function uses the format:

```
DATEDIFF(datepart, start_date, end_date)
```

It returns the difference between the *ending* date and the *starting* date, in that order.  So, in your example, if the `due` date is one day past the current date, you would get a date diff of +1.

MySQL's `DATEDIFF` computes the difference in the opposite order, namely taking the first date minus the second date, i.e.

```
DATEDIFF(date1, date2)
```

this would return the number of days which elapsed from `date2` to get to `date1`, i.e. `date1 - date2`.

Comment: 'datepart' is not a recognized datediff option. error displayed select cat_id,cust_id,date,due,DATEDIFF(datepart,date,due) as elap from rental where cat_id = '1'

Comment: Replace `datepart` with a valid value such as `dd` for days.  The purpose of my answer was mainly to explain the difference between `DATEDIFF` in SQL Server and MySQL, rather than to give you a query.

Answer (score 1):

This will work correctly.

```
select cat_id,cust_id,date,due,DATEDIFF(dd,due,GETDATE()) as elap from rental where cat_id = '1'
```